# Find the index of a special character in string in C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I wanna know if there is any standard function in visual stodio 2010, C++, which takes a character, and returns the index of it in special string, if it is exist in the string.
Tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr).

If you have a **C** like string:

```
const char *s = "hello, weird + char.";
strchr(s, '+'); // will return 13, which is '+' position within string
```

If you have a `std::string` instance:

```
std::string s = "hello, weird + char.";
strchr(s.c_str(), '+'); // 13!
```

With a `std::string` you can also a method on it to find the character you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was with my test file, I used find method.    'MyIndex= MyString.find('.');'     Tnx

Comment: `strchr` returns a pointer, not an integer. Your code is incorrect (as can be checked by following your link to the documentation)

Answer (score 3):

[`strchr`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html) or [`std::string::find`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html), depending on the type of string?

Comment: @rain: `std::wstring` and `std::string` are just specializations of `std::basic_string<>`, they offer the very same methods...

Answer (score 2):

strchr() returns a pointer to the character in the string.

```
const char *s = "hello, weird + char."; 
char *pc = strchr(s, '+'); // returns a pointer to '+' in the string
int idx = pc - s; // idx 13, which is '+' position within string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string text = "this is a sample string";
    string target = "sample";

    int idx = text.find(target);

    if (idx!=string::npos) {
        cout << "find at index: " << idx << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "not found" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `foo.cpp:13:12: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness`. Maybe use `size_t idx` and see also [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)